# How to implement generic service-layer class in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring

I try to implement generic service-layer class for basic CRUD operations.

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T, R extends JpaRepository> {

    protected R repository;

    public AbstractService(R repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public T getOne(final Long id){
        return repository.findById(id); // error Required: T, Found: Optional<>
    }
}
```

Why couldnt I use type T without wrapping it to Optional?

Comment: Because ```findById``` returns ```Optional```. You can do get on ```findById```, but there is a risk that you'll get NPE

Comment: But we want to implement Generic Type. Why we couldnt change Optional<Any> to T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always follow the good practices that are recommended for JPA and hibernate, so you must create a respository per entity, as this will allow you to develop more scalable applications, however if you want not to have to do this and want an abstract class that allows you To do this, I recommend doing an abstract Dao class that allows you to perform CRUD operations as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * @author Edy Huiza
 * @version 1.0
 * Created on 23/11/2018
 */
public interface Dao<T> {

    void persist(Object entity);

    void persist(Object[] entities);

    void update(Object entity);

    void delete(Object entity);

    void delete(Class entityClass, Serializable id);

    List findAll(Class entityClass);

    Object get(Class entityClass, Serializable id);

}
```

And their respective implementation

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
/**
 * @author Edy Huiza
 * @version 1.0
 * Created on 23/11/2018
 */
@Repository
public class SpringHibernateDao implements Dao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void persist(Object entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(Object entity) {entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void persist(Object[] entities) {
        for (Object entity : entities) {
            persist(entity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Object entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Class entityClass, Serializable id) {
        Object entity = get(entityClass, id);
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List findAll(Class entityClass) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from " + entityClass.getName()).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Object get(Class entityClass, Serializable id) {
        return entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
    }
}
```

And their respective use

```
    @Autowired
    Dao dao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Dispositivo get(long id) {
        return (Dispositivo) dao.get(Dispositivo.class, id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T, ID, R extends JpaRepository<T, ID>> {

    protected R repository;

    public AbstractService(R repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Optional<T> getOne(ID id){
        return repository.findById(id);
    }
}
```